# Parameters to use for callback to InvokeRESTAPI Azure Pipeline task

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

Following the provided documentation for the [Azure Pipeline InvokeRESTAPI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops), I am trying to use the callback feature. The `waitForCompletion` argument must be `true`, and the callback triggered as follows.

> To signal completion, the external service should POST completion data to the following pipelines REST endpoint.

```
{planUri}/{projectId}/_apis/distributedtask/hubs/{hubName}/plans/{planId}/events?api-version=2.0-preview.1

**Request Body**
{ "name": "TaskCompleted", "taskId": "taskInstanceId", "jobId": "jobId", "result": "succeeded" }
```

My problem is that I was unable to find more information about the parameters to use in the endpoint above.

- Is `{planUri}/{projectId}/` the same as `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/`?
- How can I find `hubName` and `planId`?
- I suppose that `taskId` and `jobId` are related to the Azure Pipeline that triggers the initial HTTP call, but how can one obtain them? I cannot seem to find them on the [predefined variables list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops).

This information does not seem to be available in the [distributedtask API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too was having a lot of difficulty tracking this down. Linked from the [Invoke Rest API Task docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops) is a sample project with [an image](https://msdntnarchive.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/12/completionEvent.png) showing the headers and their values mapped from Azure Pipelines variables.

They are:

```
PlanUri: $(system.CollectionUri)
ProjectId: $(system.TeamProjectId)
HubName: $(system.HostType)
PlanId: $(system.PlanId)
JobId: $(system.JobId)
TimelineId: $(system.TimelineId)
TaskInstanceId: $(system.TaskInstanceId)
AuthToken: $(system.AccessToken)
```

I'm about to give it a go with the Invoke Azure Function Task which has the same callback parameters. Wish me luck...

**EDIT**
Clearly I missed the bit in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops) where it shows that these values are set by default in the header:

```
#headers: '{Content-Type:application/json, PlanUrl: $(system.CollectionUri), ProjectId: $(system.TeamProjectId), HubName: $(system.HostType), PlanId: $(system.PlanId), JobId: $(system.JobId), TimelineId: $(system.TimelineId), TaskInstanceId: $(system.TaskInstanceId), AuthToken: $(system.AccessToken)}'
```

Comment: Did the callback work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. You can only complete the task as far as I can tell, it would be super cool if you could set the task status with the callback